# Python3.X.X Proper Setup with Virtualenv and multiple installs to /OPT/

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have spent about a week trying to get python python 3.x.x setup “properly” on my system. It has been quite a battle and I'm just about there with one final obstacle I can't seem to resolve. Many forums discuss setting up Python 3.X.X on various distro's and each has different methods, goals, outcomes, errors/issues with no clear answer. By now I have put in over 100 hours and have busted/reinstalled my system with clonzilla images dozens to times. But after all that, I have captured all the steps necessary to have the ultimate python setup in this posting - minus the answer to the final obstacle which I'm hoping someone can help me with:

The end goal I'm aiming for is the “ultimate python3.x.x setup” that I define as having the following characteristics:

- has clean installation/configurations of python3.x.x. that are built from source, and include multiple side-by-side python3.x.x. versions  (e.g. python3.0.1, python3.2.5, python3.3.0) with preserved root permissions assigned to each folder as part of the default /opt/ directory
- Each installation does not interfere with the system's default interpreter,has pip, easy install, distribute tools, and virtualenv all properly configured and working and can run in isolation with different modules via virtualenv's
- each python3.x.x is compiled, installed and named clearly in the /opt/ directory (e.g. python3.3.0, python3.3.1, python3.3.2), and is configured such that when calling whatever python3.x.x from the terminal window or using that version that it does not screwup the system's default interpretor, its dependencies/packages (plenty of forums on this one)
- Each python3.x.x is working in pycharm's stupidly simplistic and awesome virtualenv manager - my last hurdle

The following steps are my setup so far and it compiled from multiple forums necessary to accomplish all of the above minus the last hurdle. Two important points are 1) I'm running Linux Mint LTS 13 and 2) I have NOT ran “sudo apt-get install python3” or any similar apt-get of python3xxxxx (this is deliberate for reasons below).

These are the steps I have taken on a fresh install of Linux mint 13, and now have backed up clonezilla image as well as virtual box's which I'm now using to solve this last hurdle.

Step 1:
This mega-command will download and setup pycharm, including the program's oracle (sun) dependencies, and install everything to the /opt/ directory (i.e.the proper location). I simply accept oracle's prompts and complete pycharm's final installation prompts (e.g. accept license, trial period etc.)

- Pycharm

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default -y && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y && wget "http://download.jetbrains.com/python/pycharm-professional-3.0.2.tar.gz" && sudo mkdir /opt/Pycharm && sudo cp pycharm-professional-3.0.2.tar.gz /opt/Pycharm/ && cd /opt/Pycharm/ && sudo tar xvfz pycharm-professional-3.0.2.tar.gz && cd pycharm-3.0.2/bin && sudo sh pycharm.sh
  ```

Step 2:
This single command will download, extract, move, compile, and install 3.3.0, with all necessary prior dependencies, and place python3.3.0 in the /opt/ directory (the proper location).

- Python3.3.0

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential libbz2-dev bzip2 zlib1g-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev -y && wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tgz && tar xvfz Python-3.3.0.tgz && cd Python-3.3.0 && ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3.0 && make && sudo make install
  ```

Step 3: 
This single command will download, extract, move, compile, and install 3.2.5, with all necessary dependencies, and place python3.2.5 in the /opt/ directory.

- Python3.2.5

  ```
  wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2.5/Python-3.2.5.tgz && tar xvfz Python-3.2.5.tgz && cd Python-3.2.5 && ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.2.5 && make && sudo make install
  ```

We now have pycharm and two side-by-side installations of python3.3.0 and python3.2.5 that are built from source, installed in the /opt/directory, and will not interfere with the system's python2.x.x interpretor or its dependencies/packages. Good so far as this is a very clean setup... Now comes the final hurdle.

If I (or you) “sudo apt-get install python3-dev” from this point, including a few other commands to setup and activate a virtualenv of python3.x.x, everything appears to work. Meaning you can setup multiple Python3.x.x virtualenv's and run them with pycharm, eclipse or from a terminal windows as either virtualenv's or non-virtualenv's. Pycharm makes it stupidly easy to manage virtually any configuration you want with its built-in virtualenv manager. The problem though is that doing “sudo apt-get install python3-dev” defeats the whole purpose of keeping python3.x.x as separate installations and runs the risk of 1) breaking python2.x.x packages, 2) installs pip packages meant for python3.x.x. into python2.x.x directories, 3) limits the ability of the user to only python3.2 and lower because you have to point whatever virtualenv you're using to the interpreter that came with running “sudo apt-get install python3-dev”, 4) a plethora of other problems scattered throughout forums I have investigated this this week in trying to figure this all out. Therefore “sudo apt-get install python3-dev” or any other apt-get of python3.x.x is not a solution as it leads to too many issues.

At this point I have a master version of a virtual box image setup with all the above steps completed in which I keep cloning and retrying to get the compiled interpretorls from /opt/ to function without doing a “sudo apt-get python3.xxx”. The 'key problem' indicated in screen shot is this issue. Nothing I do seems to allow me to point it to /opt/python3.xx/bin/pythonX interpretor whether using an IDE like pycharm, eclipse or by terminal. As soon as I run “sudo apt-get python3.xxx” it will work – but of course inherit all the other nightmare that people scream about in forums when they go down that route. Any help is greatly appreciated...

[screenshot http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=65653](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=65653)

Every configuration I have tried in getting the interpretor's that were compiled from source fails to allow those python3.x.x installations to function as virtualenv's and thus use package managers like pip either in a terminal window or with pycharm/eclipse. I have tried installing to home directories, changing permissions in /opt/, making system links, practically everything - everything that doesn't involve a “sudo apt-get install python3.xxxx”...This post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/406756/how-to-install-python-3-x-x-properly#406762), at step two, works but only if you revert to doing a “sudo apt-get install python3”.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). It will manage your python installations, and allow you to install new versions of python without hampering other installations, it will work fine Pycharm, and will not hamper other python installations. Its done completely in bash, so it does not have python as a prerequisite installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I was not reading the make report and fixing additional dependencies before installing. The main problem was including dependencies for _ssl which is required for pip to work with python3.

I now have my "ultimate python setup"